# Excel Formula and Macro not compatible?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on creating some new macros and formulas to help automate our work in the office. We process a lot of company information, so the formula I wrote is a company identification process that marks all companies in the list as "NAV". The Macro we are using takes a combined address cell and expands it out into multiple columns (Ad1, Ad2, City, State, Zip). Both would be very handy in taking out some of the busy work that we have to deal with.

The problem that I have been experiencing is that when the formula is active in the Add-In (toggled), running the macro in file will cause Excel to time out and freeze. The formula by itself works even when the Macro is installed, and the macro runs successfully when the company identification formula is not active. I had thought that it was a memory issue, but I am running this in Excel 2016 64 Bit, which I thought was only limited by the physical memory (8GB on the tower). Is the problem actually the memory, or is there a conflict between the two processes?

The Company Identification formula is below:

```
Function NAVs(Vendor)

Dim TestVendor As String
TestVendor = UCase(Vendor)

If InStr(1, TestVendor, "ADP") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "FEDEX") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "AFLAC") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "AMERISOURCE") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "ANTHEM") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "AT&T") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "BELL SOUTH") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "BLUE CROSS") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "BLUE SHIELD") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "BLUECROSS") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "C. H. ROBINSON") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "CDW") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "CH ROBINSON") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "COMDATA") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "COSTCO") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "DEH SALES") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "DELL") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "DEPARTMENT OF TREASURY") > 0 _
    Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "ENTERGY") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "FEDERAL EX") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "FEDERAL EXPRESS") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "FED EX") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "FOOD SERVICES OF AMERICA") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "FRITO LAY") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "GRAINGER") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "INTERNAL REVENUE") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "IRS") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "KAISER") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "MC MASTER") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "MCMASTER") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "MERRITT EQUIP") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "MICROSOFT") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "NATIONAL GYPSUM") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "OFFICE DEPOT") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "OLD DOMINION") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "OTIS ELEVATOR") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "OWENS & MINOR") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "OWENS AND MINOR") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "OWENS&MINOR") > 0 _
    Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "PEPSI") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "PERMANENTE") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "PITNEY BOWES") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "PSE & G") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "PSE&G") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "PURCHASE POWER") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "QUILL") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "STAPLES") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "UNITED PARCEL SERVICE") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "UNITED STATES TREASURY") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "UPS") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "US FOODS") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "US FOODSERVICE") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "US TREASURY") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "VERIZON") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "WASTE MANAGEMENT") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, "XEROX") > 0 _
Then NAVs = "NAV"

End Function
```

The Address Splitter macro is:

```
Sub Splitter()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next

SelCol = ActiveCell.Column

Blanks = 0
CurRow = 1
Header = 0
LastRow = 0

CityList = shtCity.Range("CityList").Column

Do Until Blanks = 10
    If Cells(CurRow, SelCol) = "" Then
    Blanks = Blanks + 1
    Else
    Blanks = 0

        If Header = 0 Then
        Header = CurRow
        Else
        LastRow = CurRow
        End If
    End If

CurRow = CurRow + 1
Loop

If LastRow > Header Then
CityRow = 1

    Do Until shtCity.Cells(CityRow, 1) = ""
    Range(Cells(Header + 1, SelCol), Cells(LastRow, SelCol)).Replace    What:=shtCity.Cells(CityRow, 1), Replacement:=VBA.Replace(shtCity.Cells(CityRow, 1), " ", "ZZZ"), Lookat:=xlPart
    CityRow = CityRow + 1
    Loop

Columns(SelCol).Insert
Columns(SelCol).Insert
Columns(SelCol).Insert
Columns(SelCol).Insert
Cells(Header, SelCol) = "AD1"
Cells(Header, SelCol + 1) = "AD2"
Cells(Header, SelCol + 2) = "City"
Cells(Header, SelCol + 3) = "State"
Cells(Header, SelCol + 4) = "Zip"

    For n = Header + 1 To LastRow
    TextStr = VBA.Trim(VBA.Replace(Cells(n, SelCol + 4), ",", " "))
    LastSpace = VBA.InStrRev(TextStr, " ")

        If LastSpace = 0 Then GoTo Nextn

    Cells(n, SelCol + 4) = VBA.Trim(VBA.Mid(TextStr, LastSpace))

        If VBA.IsNumeric(VBA.Replace(Cells(n, SelCol + 4), "-", "") * 1) = False Or (VBA.Len(Cells(n, SelCol + 4)) <> 5 And VBA.Len(Cells(n, SelCol + 4)) <> 10) Then
        Cells(n, SelCol + 4) = ""
            GoTo StateCodeList
        End If

    TextStr = VBA.Trim(VBA.Left(TextStr, LastSpace))
    LastSpace = VBA.InStrRev(TextStr, " ")

        If LastSpace = 0 Then GoTo Nextn
StateCodeList:
        If LastSpace <> VBA.Len(TextStr) - 2 Then GoTo NoStateCode

    Cells(n, SelCol + 3) = VBA.Right(TextStr, 2)
    TextStr = VBA.Trim(VBA.Replace(VBA.Left(TextStr, VBA.Len(TextStr) - 2), ",", " "))
    LastSpace = VBA.InStrRev(TextStr, " ")

        If LastSpace = 0 Then GoTo Nextn
NoStateCode:
    Cells(n, SelCol + 2) = VBA.Replace(VBA.Trim(VBA.Mid(TextStr, LastSpace)), "ZZZ", " ")
    TextStr = VBA.Replace(VBA.Trim(VBA.Left(TextStr, LastSpace)), ",", " ")

    SearchStr = VBA.InStr(1, TextStr, "P.O.")

        If SearchStr > 1 Then
        Cells(n, SelCol) = VBA.Trim(VBA.Left(TextStr, SearchStr - 1))
        Cells(n, SelCol + 1) = VBA.Trim(VBA.Mid(TextStr, SearchStr))
            GoTo Nextn
        End If

    SearchStr = VBA.InStr(1, VBA.UCase(TextStr), "PO BOX")

        If SearchStr > 1 Then
        Cells(n, SelCol) = VBA.Trim(VBA.Left(TextStr, SearchStr - 1))
        Cells(n, SelCol + 1) = VBA.Trim(VBA.Mid(TextStr, SearchStr))
            GoTo Nextn
        End If

    Cells(n, SelCol) = TextStr
Nextn:
    Next n

Range(Columns(SelCol), Columns(SelCol + 4)).AutoFit
End If

Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub ShiftLeft()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error GoTo Exitsub

SelCol = ActiveCell.Column
SelRow = ActiveCell.Row

TextStr = VBA.Trim(Cells(SelRow, SelCol))
LastSpace = VBA.InStr(TextStr, " ")

If LastSpace = 0 Then
Cells(SelRow, SelCol) = ""
Cells(SelRow, SelCol - 1) = VBA.Trim(VBA.Trim(Cells(SelRow, SelCol - 1)) & " " & TextStr)
Cells(SelRow, SelCol - 1).Select
Else
Cells(SelRow, SelCol - 1) = VBA.Trim(Cells(SelRow, SelCol - 1) & " " & VBA.Trim(VBA.Left(TextStr, LastSpace - 1)))
Cells(SelRow, SelCol) = VBA.Trim(VBA.Mid(TextStr, LastSpace))
End If

Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub ShiftRight()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error GoTo Exitsub

SelCol = ActiveCell.Column
SelRow = ActiveCell.Row

TextStr = VBA.Trim(Cells(SelRow, SelCol))
LastSpace = VBA.InStrRev(TextStr, " ")

If LastSpace = 0 Then
Cells(SelRow, SelCol) = ""
Cells(SelRow, SelCol + 1) = VBA.Trim(TextStr & " " & VBA.Trim(Cells(SelRow, SelCol + 1)))
Cells(SelRow, SelCol + 1).Select
Else
Cells(SelRow, SelCol + 1) = VBA.Trim(VBA.Trim(VBA.Mid(TextStr, LastSpace)) & " " & Cells(SelRow, SelCol + 1))
Cells(SelRow, SelCol) = VBA.Trim(VBA.Left(TextStr, LastSpace - 1))
End If

Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried looking up a solution to this on the forums and online but I was unable to find anything. It does not seem like it is a memory limitation thing, though I realize it can be. Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the complexity of `Navs` by moving the target names into an array and looping:

```
Function NAVs(Vendor)

    Dim TestVendor As String
    Dim target As Variant, i As Long
    TestVendor = UCase(Vendor)

    target = Array("ADP", "FEDEX", "AFLAC", "AMERISOURCE", "ANTHEM", "AT&T", "BELL SOUTH", "BLUE CROSS", "BLUE SHIELD", _
                   "BLUECROSS", "C. H. ROBINSON", "CDW", "CH ROBINSON", "COMDATA", "COSTCO", "DEH SALES", "DELL", _
                   "DEPARTMENT OF TREASURY", "ENTERGY", "FEDERAL EX", "FEDERAL EXPRESS", "FED EX", _
                   "FOOD SERVICES OF AMERICA", "FRITO LAY", "GRAINGER", "INTERNAL REVENUE", "IRS", "KAISER", _
                   "MC MASTER", "MCMASTER", "MERRITT EQUIP", "MICROSOFT", "NATIONAL GYPSUM", "OFFICE DEPOT", _
                   "OLD DOMINION", "OTIS ELEVATOR", "OWENS & MINOR", "OWENS AND MINOR", "OWENS&MINOR", _
                   "PEPSI", "PERMANENTE", "PITNEY BOWES", "PSE & G", "PSE&G", "PURCHASE POWER", "QUILL", _
                   "STAPLES", "UNITED PARCEL SERVICE", "UNITED STATES TREASURY", "UPS", "US FOODS", _
                   "US FOODSERVICE", "US TREASURY", "VERIZON", "WASTE MANAGEMENT", "XEROX")
    For i = 0 To UBound(target)
        If InStr(1, TestVendor, target(i)) > 0 Then
            NAVs = "NAV"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

As an added benefit -- this returns as soon as there is a match but VBA doesn't use short-circuit evaluation of `Or` so your original version would evaluate each clause every time.

Whether or not this will solve your problem -- I have no idea. Try and see.

Comment: You can use excel to separate these out with Text to columns, using the double quote as a seperator. then just find replace ") > 0 Or InStr(1, TestVendor, " with blanks, and use goto to delete blank cells. [This](http://pastebin.com/GfHUdemn) is the full list after that process.

Comment: @AndrewWynn I started by pasting that Or statement into Notepad and doing some replaces but still had some noise when I pasted the result into VBA which I removed manually. It should be accurate but I didn't want to bet the farm on it. Your approach seems less error-prone than what I did.

Comment: @AndrewWynn I just checked my list against yours and saw that they both had 56 elements, so I removed the disclaimer I had at the end of my answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thank you John! I was positive that there had to be a way to organize my IF statements into an Array, but I was unable to find how to do so. This ended up working and stopped my Excel from crashing when I ran the earlier Macro. I will try implementing your solution as well Andrew, it sounds like it would clean up my results after running the formula

Comment: @PaulCalvert Glad it worked for you. Note that if some of the vendors like "Fed Ex" are more common than others than moving them earlier in the array could speed things up -- so sorting them by how common they are might help. Also note that if "Federal Express" is in your string then so is "Federal Ex" -- so there are some redundant cases which I didn't eliminate.

Answer (score 0):

So are you using the NAVs function on the worksheet? Because Custom User Functions are a big resource hog, if you are running this on a lot of cells, it will slow down considerably, and any time you do anything, or anything changes, it has to rerun all of that code multiplied by all of the cells which contain it.

So when the splitter writes any value to a cell, it has to recalculate all NAVs again. Every single time.

I would recommend instead using the function off-sheet whenever you need it, as it looks like it doesn't need to recalculate at all, so just do something like this:

```
Sub DispNavs()
    Dim cel as Range
    For each cel in Range("Put a range here, in the format A1:A500")
        cel.offset(,1).value = Navs(cel.value)
    Next cel
End Sub
```

This will write the value returned by your function into the cells to the right of the range you provide, and of course, you should remove the function from the worksheet itself

Having said that, you could also disable calculation with `application.calculation = xlManual` at the start of your splitter module, and reenable it with `application.calculation = xlAutomatic` at the end.

Let me know how this goes, or if for some reason, neither solution helps.

Comment: I had not considered using this approach. I am writing another process to help mark personal names in a vendor list, and this may be a good way to go about it. Thanks Andrew!